# Are $f\sqrt{1+g^2}$ and $fg\sqrt{1+g^2}$ smooth if $f,fg,fg^2$ are smooth?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that the functions $f,fg,fg^2$ are smooth, that is, are in $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Does it then necessarily follow that the 
functions $f\sqrt{1+g^2}$ and $fg\sqrt{1+g^2}$ are smooth?

Of course, the problem here is that the function $g$ does not have to be smooth, or even continuous, at zeroes of the function $f$.

One may also note that the continuity of the 
functions $f\sqrt{1+g^2}$ and $fg\sqrt{1+g^2}$ (at the zeroes of $f$ and hence everywhere) follows easily from the inequalities $|f\sqrt{1+g^2}|\le|f|+|fg|$ and $|fg\sqrt{1+g^2}|\le|fg|+|fg^2|$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No.**

Set
$$ f(x) = \exp(-2/|x|^2) \operatorname{sign} x, \qquad g(x) = \exp(1/|x|^2) \sqrt{|x|} \operatorname{sign} x $$
for $x \ne 0$, and, of course, $f(0) = g(0) = 0$. Then clearly
$$ \begin{aligned}
f(x) & = \exp(-2/|x|^2) \operatorname{sign} x , \\
f(x) g(x) & = \exp(-1/|x|^2) \sqrt{|x|} , \\
f(x) (g(x))^2 & = x
\end{aligned} $$
are infinitely smooth, but
$$ f(x) g(x) \sqrt{1 + (g(x))^2} = \sqrt{|x| \exp(-2/|x|^2) + |x|^2} = |x| (1 + o(1)) $$
is not even differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Thank you for this counterexample. Just one typo, think: It seems to me that for your $f$ and $g$ we have $f(x)g(x)^2=x$ for all $x$.

Comment: There is now a follow-up question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353015/are-pm-f-sqrt1g2-and-pm-fg-sqrt1g2-smooth-if-f-fg-fg2-are-smoot

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Sure! Corrected, thanks!